# How to add a text in the column 'Ship To Name' in sales->order incase of virtual product

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, virtual-products

I have a virtual product. I know that doesn't have shipping details and hence in sales->order grid, Ship To Name column is blank but in those cases, I want to add a custom text.
How can we achieve that in magento 1.9.2.2?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml
Follow the lines of code added to add your custom message for the column 'Ship To Name' incase of virtual product.[image]
Hope this will help the needy one!
If someone gets something better, please post!

Comment: this solves you problem but it's a bad way of coding it. You are editing a template that is used by all the grids. Not a good idea.

Comment: @Marius Can you suggest something please

Comment: I'm searching now.

Answer (score 0):

you can rewrite the class and change the column configuration to include a default value.

By default the grid column looks like this

```
$this->addColumn('shipping_name', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship to Name'),
    'index' => 'shipping_name',
));
```

you can make it look like this

```
$this->addColumn('shipping_name', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship to Name'),
    'index' => 'shipping_name',
    'default' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Your default text here')
));
```

[EDIT]

An alternative would be to rewrite the grid class and implement the method `_afterLoadCollection`.
This is called after the collection that needs to be displayed is loaded. So you will only be affecting the items to be displayed.

you can make the method like this

```
protected function _afterLoadCollection()
{
    foreach ($this->getCollection() as $item) {
        if (empty(trim($item->getShippingName()))) {
            $item->setShippingName(Mage::helper('sales')->__('Your default text here'))
        }
    }
    return parent::_afterLoadCollection();
}
```

this way you change only your grid and do not affect all the grids.

Comment: I agree to your way too but this is not helping in my case. I checked, Shipping name coming as 2 spaces for virtual  product thereby default not working there. Any suggestion/idea about the issue

Comment: @AnuragKhandelwal See my edit.